# Postgresql - Sort a character field with Special characters, numbers and alphabets

Tags: database, postgresql, sorting, sql-order-by

I have the following data in one of my Postgresql table.

```
name
-----------------
AdvertiserTest123  
Advertiser ADV 833  
:1Advertiser  
02 Advertiser  
MH Advertiser
```

When I query as: `Select * from adv_names order by name;`

The output I get is

```
AdvertiserTest123  
Advertiser ADV 833  
:1Advertiser  
02 Advertiser  
MH Advertiser
```

I'm expecting the order of sorting to be name with Specials Characters followed numbers and then alphabets. If I'm not wrong this is how it behaves in Sql Server.

I tried changing collation and tried ascii search. It doesn't work the way I am expecting.  Can anyone help on this?

Expected Output:

```
:1Advertiser  
02 Advertiser  
Advertiser ADV 833  
AdvertiserTest123  
MH Advertiser
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The real question here is whether your expectation is reasonable. Sorting text values in SQL is determined by the collation. In PostgreSQL, you can change the collation when you run your query.

```
select * from adv_names order by "name" collate "POSIX";
```

It boils down to this: in which collations are special characters ordered before numbers? I don't *think* any of the collations work that way, but I could be wrong. (I don't have to think much about collations where I work.)

To see which collations are available to you, run this.

```
select * from pg_collation;
```

In a pinch, you can create your own collation.  See [create collation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createcollation.html). I'm not sure this will work for you. It depends on OS support and PostgreSQL build options.

Comment: It certainly provided a direction. Regarding my expectation ..basically I have 2 sources to extract my reports. One is sql server based and another is Postgres. Sql Server returns the output as per my expectation and hence I’m trying a way in Postgres to do the similar thing.

Comment: First, figure out what collation SQL Server is using. You might need to determine its character encoding as well. Then try to figure out which coalition on Linux does the same thing. ( I assume postgres SQL is running on Linux.)

Comment: Yes, Postgres is in Linux. Thanks . I will keep posted

Comment: The update is that there is no exact collation match from SQL server to Postgres SQL which does the sorting according to my requirement. For my problem I did a client side sorting which again has some limitations, but Im ok with it for now. Your answer works the right way for the question. So I will mark it as correct answer. Thanks for the help.